# Is a good practice reuse HTTP codes to encode something else?

Tags: clean-code, http

As we know HTTP codes are used in HTTP response. Usually with this code we can have an idea about what happened. For example if I make a get request and I obtain a 404 I can figure out that the resource that I requested doesn't exist on the server side.

Suppose that I want to encode the status of an object in the DB. For example let's say that if the object exist but some data are missing (a specific field for example) I want to save it in my DB but express the status of the object with a column. This need to be an integer (suppose it is a constraint). I would go for 206 (partial content in HTTP).

From a code point of view suppose we have an enum to express the various possible status as this one:

```
public enum ValidationStatus {

    OK(HttpStatus.OK.value()),
    PARTIAL(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT.value()),
    ...

    private final Integer code;
    ...
```

When someone reads the code, it seems that HTTP is involved in some way. But in this case it’s not. I'm reusing the HTTP status to represent something else.

I saw that in a project but I'm not sure about if this is a good practise. It’s like mixing things for me. I'm using something created for HTTP to represent something else.

Do you think that it is acceptable?

**EDIT**: to be more precise my was just an example of reusing HTTP code in other context. Actually in the DB is stored the string value (in this case PARTIAL) but in this microservices application, the services communicate with messages and in these messages you find the integer. When for example an object is in the status PARTIAL a notification is send to another service as if it is a sort of error. This question arose when I was running some tests, and in the log I so this: "ERROR 206 PARTIAL". I saw this and the HTTP 206 status came into my mind. After that I discovered the use of this code in the application and so the enum class. My initial confusion brought me to ask this question. The I discovered that HTTP was not involved at all.

Comment: Two things can be similar without needing to be related, and arbitrary values are inherently at your discretion. I'm not sure how much more specific of an answer you're looking for here.

Comment: > Suppose that I want to encode the status of an object in the DB

Why do you want to do that? Why should the system calling your API care what's in the DB? Don't they just care about what they can get back in the response?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. Seems like a perfectly fine question to me. So I upvoted it.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of what the 206 status means. You wouldn't be reusing the status. You would be *redefining* it. Related StackOverflow question: [What does the HTTP 206 Partial Content status message mean and how do I fully load resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15787380/3092298)

Comment: This reminds me of the way that XML namespaces are declaring using strings that look exactly like internet endpoints. There have been a few times that engineers on my team were mixed up because of this, e.g. when looking through logs. I can see why the designers of the format decided to do it that way, but sometimes I wish namespaces were a different format entirely.

Comment: @JohnWu totally unrelated but XML namespaces are URI (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces) and unfortunately most people limit those to URL even if those urls point to nowhere... It is perfectly valid to use namespaces that don't start with "http://" which would cause far less confusion about what namespaces are...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's not just the format, it's the ecosystem. Do you know how many times I've been told that our problem is a service located at [`tempuri.org`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would advise against it. The most likely result is that you will create confusion with future developers/maintainers.

- You are using the codes outside of the context of HTTP, so you will probably get questions about what happened to the status codes with values 0 to 199. In the database, the fact that the codes begin at 200 does not have any inherent meaning.
- As mentioned in another answer, the HTTP status codes may not be specific enough, so you would have to invent new values that you have to give a meaning yourself (and which may conflict with future HTTP status codes).

After you have had to invent your first application-specific status code, any advantage you may have had previously that the values were 'well known' and didn't need to be documented by you is now gone as well and there is no reason left not to do the conventional thing and count your status values from 1 (or 0).

Comment: Even in the context of HTTP there are really just handful of codes that are well understood (200 - here, 301/302 - there, 404 - not here, 500 - everything is broken, and maybe 401/403 - tell me who you are). All other codes are rare enough that most people will have to dig out the definition and even then expect incorrect usage anyway...

Comment: _After you have had to invent your first application-specific status code, any advantage you may have had previously that the values were 'well known' is now gone_ - why? I can still easily remember those handful of codes that we re-used, and for others - I'd have to look them up each time I forget.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev because if they look like HTTP codes they will be used as HTTP codes whether one accounted for it or not. And the once that are not valid HTTP codes will randomly cause interesting day long investigations...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, well that's quite a stretch.. And I'm pretty sure Bart was talking about something else.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev, it is not that much of a stretch.If you intentionally style your status codes after the HTTP codes, then you probably also refer to the HTTP documentation for the meaning of them (at least until you have a case that *isn't* covered by an HTTP code). And then that will become the primary source of information, even when it is no longer fitting.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, the "stretch" was that someone would start using those statuses for actual HTTP responses. As for referring to HTTP docs, it's simple: you either have an HTTP code and reference the spec; or you don't and you don't reference the spec. No confusion at all.

Comment: "I can remember those handful of codes" - sounds great for exactly one person working on a single project, and just terrible for multiple people (who need to guess which idiot memorized something instead of documenting it), or for working on multiple projects and coming back to this one 18 months later, or for ever handing it over to somebody else ...

Comment: @Useless, did you read the question and my posts? Of course everything is documented, moreover, those constants aren't just numbers - they are enums. It's unfortunate that still none of the opponents of the suggested scheme has listed any _practical_ reason why not - just hand waving :(

Answer (score 2):

In a multi-tiered architecture, the business layer should have no knowledge of the transport. That allows the same code to run in a web service, on a desktop, or on a phone. Or possibly in your thermostat. Let me give you a practical example of this.

Let's say you want to use HTTP status codes in your business layer, so your developer adds a dependency to `System.Web`. Now you're going to have to deploy `System.Web` everywhere your business logic is going to live, including places where it might make absolutely no sense, or where it does make sense to have a `System.Web` but your business layer was built with the wrong version. When that happens, you may have to version your web platform and business objects in lockstep, which reduces your deployment agility.

Your business layer should define its own enumeration for its own business concepts. If you like, its numeric values can "coincidentally" be 200 for OK and 404 for not found, but it should be a list of codes in its own right that you own.

Answer (score -4):

This seems like a very nice idea. It's great when we can re-use ideas from other areas - this way we can reuse our knowledge instead of learning purely new concepts in each context.

However HTTP codes are often vague and not precise, you won't be able to express many of your custom statuses with HTTP. So I'd go like this:

1. If the status clearly resembles an HTTP response code - re-use it
2. If your status is not entirely consistent with HTTP - come up with your own code. Otherwise it'll be confusing.

A possible downside: if your statuses are always sequential, then sometimes it's useful to use their integer values to check if we're passed some status or not. HTTP codes won't allow this. On the other hand - such needs aren't that common and you may create additional "stage" attribute to your enum for that.

**To downvoters** - please comment on why you think it's a bad idea. Describe what *harm* do you think will come from re-using HTTP codes.

Comment: HTTP status codes aren't really designed for this.

Comment: This looked good up to the point of recommending defining custom status codes. That could put your application in conflict with future versions of the HTTP protocol. Then you are right back in the territory @Zach describes in his answer.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, Zach's answer is offtopic, he misunderstood the question. This question is NOT about HTTP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what do you mean they are not "designed" for this? It's your app design that we're discussing, not HTTP. You can't break HTTP by re-using its numbers elsewhere. Of course they won't cover all your custom statuses of your custom app. But whenever there's an intersection, there's no harm in re-using the same numbers. After all, the database won't care which number you keep in your column. _You_ give meaning to the number. And if that number is easier to remember just because it's coming from some well known spec - that's great, this just simplifies the memorization of those codes.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev: You cannot discuss HTTP without also discussing HTTP codes.